# Django select last rows of all types

Tags: django, select

In django I have a table that contains rows with these columns:
 "id", "type" , "inserted_date".

I would like to know the ids of last inserted rows of all types. 
How can I do this in django?

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: Do you use a timestamp in your model? Note that primary keys are not a *reliable* way to know what has been inserted the last time.

Comment: I use Mysql, and I would like to use a timestamp (the "inserted_date" I specified in the text above) to get what was last inserted

Comment: At least I did it with a raw query